# How do is use both the keyboard an mouse controler at the same time

Tags: python, pynput

When I use "import pynput as" the button thing isnt imported, AttributeError: 'Controller' object has no attribute 'Button'

However, when I import from it gets confused as what "controler" is which because they arent named, what do I do? How do I get the two to work at the same time?

```
import pynput.mouse    as ms
import pynput.keyboard as kb
import  time
import  stuff



mouse = ms.Controller()
keybord = kb.Controller()


while True:

    time.sleep(3)


    keybord.position = (454, 78)
    keybord.press(Button.left)
    keybord.release(Button.left)

    mouse.press(Key.ctrl)
    mouse.press('a')
    mouse.release('a')
    mouse.release(Key.ctrl)

    mouse.press(Key.ctrl)
    mouse.press('v')
    mouse.release('v')
    mouse.release(Key.ctrl)

    mouse.press(Key.enter)
    mouse.release(Key.enter)
```

Comment: `Button` is apparently an attribute of `pynput.mouse`.  Since you imported that submodule as `ms`, you can use `ms.Button` to refer to this attribute.  Or you could do `from pynput.mouse import Button` and leave your code as it is.

Comment: that doesnt work, i get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_dead'

Comment: If my answer helped, consider to accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Some changes:

1. You didn't import the `Key`, `Button`.
2. You use the `keyboard` and `mouse` in a incorrect way.That's why it would raise error:
   `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_dead'`

This code worked for me:

```
import pynput.mouse as ms
from pynput.keyboard import Key
import pynput.keyboard as kb
from pynput.mouse import Button
import time



mouse = ms.Controller()
keybord = kb.Controller()

while True:
    time.sleep(3)

    mouse.position = (454, 78)
    mouse.press(Button.left)
    mouse.release(Button.left)

    keybord.press(Key.ctrl)
    keybord.press('a')
    keybord.release('a')
    keybord.release(Key.ctrl)

    keybord.press(Key.ctrl)
    keybord.press('v')
    keybord.release('v')
    keybord.release(Key.ctrl)

    keybord.press(Key.enter)
    keybord.release(Key.enter)
```